Closed-form for 3F2(1)?
While working on a combinatorics/ graph theory problem, I've encountered a generalized hypergeometric function of the form
$$
{}_3F_2(-l,-m,-n;1/2,1-\alpha-l-m-n;1)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-l)_k (-m)_k (-n)_k}{(1/2)_k (1-\alpha-l-m-n)_k k!},
$$
where $l$, $m$, and $n$ are nonnegative integers, and $\alpha$ is positive. Unless it is possible to simplify this function, I'm afraid I cannot progress any further on the overarching problem.
It seems to be very close to the case of Saalschütz's theorem, which for the present parameters ($a_1=-l$, $a_2=-m$, $a_3=-n$, and $b_1=1/2$) reads
$$
{}_3F_2(-l,-m,-n;1/2,1-1/2-l-m-n,1)=\frac{(1/2+l)_n(1/2+m)_n}{(1/2)_n(1/2+l+m)_n}.
$$
Of course, my problem reduces to Saalschütz's when $\alpha=1/2$, but I haven't any clue how to generalize the result to include my case. I am not particularly well-versed in the literature on generalized hypergeometric functions, but I am aware of results like Wimp's theorem, which prohibits some generalizations of Watson's summation theorem.
Is the function ${}_3F_2(-l,-m,-n;1/2,1-\alpha-l-m-n;1)$ expressible in terms of gamma functions or Pochhammer symbols? Or in any closed form?
